# Sencha Touch input field keydown event not firing

Tags: extjs, keydown

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'weight',
    minValue: 10,
    maxValue: 1000,
    placeHolder: 'WEIGHT',
    cls: 'GoldWtLayout',
    id: 'GoldWtKgLayoutMum',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    listeners: {
        keydown: function(){
            alert('keydown');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Number), `numberfield` doesnt seem to have a `keydown` listener. You can probably have a look at `mousedown` listener.

**Edit**

Come to think of it, you probably want to use the [keyup](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Number-event-keyup) event listener.

Comment: But mousedown event will fire only once ? like focus ? cos i tried, it is wrkin only once

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen when the `numberfield` is pressed?

Comment: I want to change data in other field when numberfield is pressed